# Reordering UITableView with NSOrderedSet in CoreData

Tags: core-data, ios5, xcode4.2, uitableview

Does anyone has sample code for ordering in UITableView using NSOrderedSet?

Had read many articles about reordering, but still don't understand how to do this in iOS5.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360938/uitableview-core-data-reordering This is quite helpful, but...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi i implemented it like this. The "currentObject" is root object of the relationship and "subItems" the name of the ordered relationship in the model which is managed by the UITableViewController.

```
 - (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {

   NSMutableOrderedSet* orderedSet = [self.currentObject mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"subItems"];

   NSInteger fromIndex = fromIndexPath.row;
   NSInteger toIndex = toIndexPath.row;

   // see  http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=74
   NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:fromIndex];

   if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
    // we're moving up
    [orderedSet moveObjectsAtIndexes:indexes toIndex:toIndex];
   } else {
    // we're moving down
    [orderedSet moveObjectsAtIndexes:indexes toIndex:toIndex-[indexes count]];
   }

   [self.dataStore saveObjectContext];
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Stephan, I am using FRC how to to do this using FRC

Comment: Hi @Ranjit as far as I know a NSFetchedResultController don't have access to the arbitrary order of a NSMutableOrderedSet. I mean there is now way to fetch it. You can fetch for the root object but I guess this is not what you want. Therefore I use in projects where i use FRC the attribute solution and not a ordered-relationship. The seconed disadvantage is IMHO iCloud don't support NSMutableOrderedSet yet.

Comment: Hi @Stephan, If we use an attribute to maintain the order of items, then suppose I have 100 items and I delete any of the middle item, I have to recalculate the order attribute values and doing that every time will be a headache

Comment: @Ranjit this dependes of how you implement this. But this is of topic of this question. Take a look on my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077568/ and my ref implementation