# Automatic re-ordering of Core Data in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to reorder a my Core Data list when moving cells in "Edit Mode".  There seems to be helpful discussion in this area for Obj-c (see links below), but I can't find anything in Swift.

Has anyone come across any related documentation for Swift?  Or would anyone be willing to translate the obj-c code to Swift?  Thanks!

Obj-c links:

[How can I maintain display order in UITableView using Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648223/how-can-i-maintain-display-order-in-uitableview-using-core-data/1648504#1648504)

[How to implement re-ordering of CoreData records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077568/how-to-implement-re-ordering-of-coredata-records)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow isn't a translation service.  Generally speaking, for the foreseeable future Swift development will require at least being able to read Objective-C.  Give it a shot, and come back with specific questions.

Comment: There are two questions there, aren't there?  Couldn't you have just deleted the question re the translation?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice way I do it. It also checks if the destination may not contain any data and you can also move accross sections.
isMoving will inhibit the delegate from firing off. You also need a sortorder attribute at your entity.

```
private func indexIsOutOfRange(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if indexPath.section > self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.count - 1 {
        return true
    }
    if indexPath.row > self.fetchedResultsController.sections![indexPath.section].objects!.count - 1 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if indexIsOutOfRange(destinationIndexPath) {
        return
    }

    isMovingItem = true


    if sourceIndexPath.section == destinationIndexPath.section {
        if var todos = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![sourceIndexPath.section].objects {
            let todo = todos[sourceIndexPath.row] as! FoodEntry
            todos.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
            todos.insert(todo, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)

            var idx = 1
            for todo in todos as! [FoodEntry] {
                todo.sortOrder = NSNumber(integer: idx++)
            }
            try!managedObjectContext.save()
        }
    } else {

        if var allObjectInSourceSection = fetchedResultsController.sections![sourceIndexPath.section].objects {
            let object = allObjectInSourceSection[sourceIndexPath.row] as! FoodEntry
            allObjectInSourceSection.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)

            for (index,object) in (allObjectInSourceSection as! [FoodEntry]).enumerate() {
                object.sortOrder = NSNumber(integer: index)
            }


            if var allObjectInDestinationSection = fetchedResultsController.sections![destinationIndexPath.section].objects {

                allObjectInDestinationSection.insert(object, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)

                for (index,object) in (allObjectInDestinationSection as! [FoodEntry]).enumerate() {
                    object.sortOrder = NSNumber(integer: index)
                    object.section = NSNumber(integer: destinationIndexPath.section)
                }
            }
        }

    }


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    })

    isMovingItem = false

    try!managedObjectContext.save()

    fetch()

}
```

Comment: Timm, I've implemented this approach with a few minor changes. One being that I do used the reloadRoasAtIndexPath, I let the didChange anObject method handle reloading. I'm curious what the isMovingItem does, when I comment the code out everything works perfectly fine. Obviously my code is different but if you could briefly explain the use that would be most helpful. +1 btw