# NSFetchedResultsController - My _sectionNameKeyPath_ is _nil_ !! Why am I getting this error when adding / deleting?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios4, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Classic case of the sections issue with NSFetchedResultsController and I am pulling my hair out. I have set the *sectionNameKeyPath* to **NIL** which I've read is what you want for no sections (i.e 1 section).

Code as follows:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"MyObjectType" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                              initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"accountExpenseTypeCache"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    [sort release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [theFetchedResultsController release];


    return _fetchedResultsController;  
    }
```

As you can see my *sectionNameKeyPath* is set to nil and

Sometimes when I add or delete a row, it works. Most often than not I get this serious crash in the console though when trying to delete or add:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UITableView.m:955
(gdb) continue
2011-03-14 18:00:58.104 MyApplicationTest[5741:207] Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted). with userInfo (null)
```

What's the issue? I was reading the NSFetchedResultsController prior to 4.0 was built to handle User Driven updates? I can only assume adding and deleting rows are considered User Driven updates? Do I need to implement something like this?

[How to implement re-ordering of CoreData records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077568/how-to-implement-re-ordering-of-coredata-records)

?? From what I've read though I don't understand why I have this issue when I have nil for sections. Why is it saying that are 3 sections?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your datasource methods for the tableview. Looks like you might be returning something different than your fetchedResultsController sectionInfo data in the `numberOfSections` method?

Comment: -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {  
 NSLog(@"Sections: %d", [[_fetchedResultsController sections] count]);
 return [[_fetchedResultsController sections] count];
 
    }  @Rog nope :(

Comment: UPDATE: It looks like the crash only happens on the very **first** time I try to add or delete a record. If in console I hit **continue** the app recovers and further additions and deletions work fine. If I close the app and restart - again on the first add or delete it crashes with the above error.

Comment: So before the crash, what do you see? Is the tableview rendering as expected (i.e. 1 section only?). What about post crash?

Comment: @Rog correct. Before an add / delete the tableview renders as expected (1 section only.) Post crash - it renders correctly as well but this is only **after** I click CONTINUE in console.

Answer (score 1):

The number of sections in the tableview is not dependent on the `sectionNameKeyPath` of the fetched results controller but rather by the returned by the datasource's `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

The error you are getting can be triggered by not sending the tableview a `beginUpdate` message prior to changing the data. The tableview may try to redraw itself while the count of the data is in flux.

You must also implement the fetched results controller's delegate methods in the tableview's datasource object so that table is signaled when a change occurs.

Comment: All the fetched results controller's delegate methods DO exist and are implemented. I've double checked that `beginUpdate` is called. Resolved this issue myself and I forget what it was but it had something to do using an incorrect managedObjectContext.