# Unable to move rows in a UITableView even when grabber are displaying

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a somewhat weird issue, and I can't quite figure out what am I missing. I have a UITableView which is editable in place (i.e. when my UI is loaded, I send my table the setEditing:YES animated:YES message). The last row in the table is intended to be the "Add New" row. All rows except the last row in my table can be moved around. None of the rows can be deleted.

The rows show up correctly, and the grabbers shows up on the right side of all rows except the last row (as intended). **The problem is that I am unable to move the rows. When I tap on the grabber to move the row, it kind of jiggles in place, but I can't drag it up or down.** Here's the relevant snippet of code:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
    if (indexPath.row == [self.itemArray count] ) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == [self.itemArray count]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    Item *item = [self.itemArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.itemArray removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.itemArray insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
    if ([proposedDestinationIndexPath row] < [self.itemArray count]) {
        return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
    }
    NSIndexPath *betterIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.itemArray count]-1 inSection:0];
    return betterIndexPath;
}
```

On trying to debug, it seems that the tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath: gets called almost immediately even as I am holding on to the grabber (i.e. I have not lifted my finger yet). Moreover, my tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:proposedDestinationIndexPath: does not get invoked at all.

Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong? Any suggestions on what I should try to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't drag UITableViewCell from its current position when reorder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251735/cant-drag-uitableviewcell-from-its-current-position-when-reorder)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had this problem too. Check if you have a UIGestureRecognizer (for me it was a UIPanGestureRecognizer) that is attached to the UITableView's superviews. I removed it and the reordering worked.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem as I eventually figured out.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem, and @wilsontgh & @Andy responses took me in the right direction. However I couldn't afford removing the needed PanRecognizer from the superview, nor disabling it in certain views.
What worked for me was to set this on the main view recognizer, which avoids cancelling touches handled to other views/recognizers.

```
panRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Comment: This is a great solution to what is a *very* annoying situation.  I was using ViewDeck which manages a Facebook style overflow/navigation menu and so the pan gesture recognizer in the parent view was wreaking havoc with the tableview's gesture recognizer.  Cheers.

Comment: To fix ViewDeck I was able to set `panningCancelsTouchesInView` to false in my `IIViewDeckController`

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner!!

Comment: Thanks for @nobre. For my case, I did this for the tableview which is referenced from the storyboard: self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it is the "hide nav bar on swipe" feature that caused the re-order to fail. Therefore make sure it is turned off if you need the UITableView re-order feature.

`navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false`

Note that navigation controller is shared across all view controllers of the same navigation stack, therefore one screen can affect all other ones even after pushing/pop-ing operations.

Comment: I'm updating my app for iOS 13 and this is exactly the problem I was having. I would start to drag an item and then the navigation bar would slide away upwards. Had no idea why as I had other views that worked fine. I never even set hidesBarOnSwipe anywhere in my app other than a website view controller which I wasn't even displaying at the moment. But setting hidesBarOnSwipe to NO (Obj-C) solved this problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem and this thread pointed me in the right direction, but the better approach is to use the gesture recognizer's delegate method gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: to determine if you are in a situation where you want to process it or not.

In my situation I had a swipe gesture on a main view controller and was displaying a table in a child view controller. In gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: I return a NO when the child view controller is active, which allows the table to see every gesture and the container view controller doesn't handle anything.

Answer (score 1):

The method `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` does get called immediately upon touching the control. From the [UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> The UITableView object sends this message to the data source when the user presses the reorder control in fromRow.

So this is expected behavior.

I believe the problem is in your `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`. Do you have a specific reason to include this method? Have you tried leaving it out and going with the proposed position?

For example, it seems that `([proposedDestinationIndexPath row] < [self.itemArray count])` will always return `true`...

Comment: Even getting rid of the tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath: method does not solve the problem. The intent behind this method is that the last row (the "Add New" row) should not be moved, and no other rows can be moved below it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in the `keyboardDismissMode` property.