# Reorder/move UITableViewCell but moves back

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to implement a method to be able to reorder the rows of a tableview.
In each section i only have one row. When the editing-state of the tableview is enabled, the move indicators appear as expacted. But when i drag one of the cell to another position, the cell immediatly (after approximatly 1 s) pops back to the original position. This is weired to me, because i implemented such a reorder functionality already. The difference between those two projects are that the new project implements a bunch of gesture recognizers (eg **UILongPressGestureRecognizer**, **UIPanGestureRecognizer**, UIPinchGestureRecognizer,..). I already thought about the possibility that one of the gesture recognizers is blocking the drag action of the tableviewcell but its not.

You can see the code below:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YES;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {

    //return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:3];

    return nil;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

    NSLog(@"%@", destinationIndexPath);
}
```

Can anyone help me pls?

**UPDATE:**

I found out that the moved tableviewcell is beeing moved to the original destination index path. Does that indicate, that a reloadData on the table view has happened?

**2nd UPDATE:**

Because it was menthioned by Andrei Shender why i return nil in the *tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:* method you can find my updated code below.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;

   //for testing purpose only
   //return nil;
}
```

Btw when changing my code, i found out, that this method never gets called. Regarding to [Apples documents about reordering tableviewcells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html) it should get called.

Comment: Why do you return a nil in this method:
`tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`

Comment: Hi, good point! But it was just for testing. In my current update i return the proposed destination index path. I'll update my code

Comment: Where is the code that actually changes your dataSource in `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`?

Comment: I'm currently programming on this part, i'll post my solution when its done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953706/unable-to-move-rows-in-a-uitableview-even-when-grabber-are-displaying) I figured out, what the problem was. Combining a UIPanGestureRecognizer and a UITableView with the reorder/move funcationality is a tricky thing.

When i edit the tableview, i remove the gesture recognizer (of the viewcontroller's view) and when the editing is disabled again, i add the gesture recognizer again.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to update your data source in the method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
```