# iOS UITableView is getting stuck in edit mode when reordering cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

iOS UITableView is getting stuck in edit mode when reordering cells

When I click on Edit, edit mode enters correctly and when I click done it correctly gets out of edit mode.

But when I drag and reorder cells, the table gets stuck in edit mode, see attached.  The only way out of it is to kill the app.

This is happing in iOS 6 and 7.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
    - (IBAction)editAction:(id)sender
        {
                [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        }
    - (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender
{
                [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            return YES;
        }
        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
        {
            self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;

            NSMutableArray *objects = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

            id object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];

            [objects removeObject:object];
            [objects insertObject:object atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];
            int i = 0;
            for (NSManagedObject *mo in objects) [mo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
            objects = nil;


            [[self currentManagedObjectContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

            self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

            [[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:nil];
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to show some code for how you're handling the edit. Does this happen if you don't complete the edit?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand how you're trying to edit the table.  Are you just wanting to move cells, or do you also want to delete cells (because you're not setting an editing style on the table `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` delegate)?  The more detail you can provide about what you expect to happen and what is actually happening, the easier it will be to help.

Comment: This is what I would like.  Tap edit...user ability to move cells. I have working logic that the user can select the cell and do a multiple delete.  The logic works correctly to move the cells.  The problem comes when you tap done to go back to non-editing mode.  It just gets stuck in the editing mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution from this issue and corrected the issue:

[How to implement re-ordering of CoreData records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077568/how-to-implement-re-ordering-of-coredata-records)