# Edit rows position in a table view with Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

i know there are many questions about this, but i looked each one of them without finding a solution for me.
I got the code for editing the positions of the rows in a table view from a tutorial, and it works perfectly, but whenever i change view and then go back to the tableView page (i think that occurs the ViewDidAppear method) all the edited rows go back to their previous position.
This is my code:

Edit action related to the button:

```
- (void)editAction:(id)sender
{
    if(self.editing)
    {
        [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [[self tableView] setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [[self tableView] reloadData];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
        [_tableData removeAllObjects];
    }
    else
    {
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [[self tableView] setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [[self tableView] reloadData];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
        [_tableData removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Methods for editing:

```
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSString *item = [self.datas objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.datas removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.datas insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

}

// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
```

ViewDidAppear

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [_tableData removeAllObjects];
    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Data"];
    self.datas = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [_searchDati objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
        NSString *string;
        //configure cells
        NSManagedObject *data = [self.datas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [data valueForKey:@"name"]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:nil];
        cell.textLabel.text = string;

        //tableData array used for filtering
        [_tableData addObject:string];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

the NSMutableArray tableData is used only for the `UISearchbar`.
I can't figure out where is the problem. The Core Data are related to the `@property (strong) NSMutableArray *datas;` so i thought that modifying the `datas` array there should be no problem, but maybe it's not the right thing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach:

- `executeFetchRequest:` returns an `NSArray` of managed objects, but the order of the
  elements is unspecified, unless you add a sort descriptor to the fetch request.
- Your `self.data` is a *mutable copy* of the fetched objects, and reordering the elements
  of `self.data` has no effect at all on the Core Data objects.

Therefore, when you change the view and come back to this table view, all elements
will have the same (unspecified) order as when the program started.

To keep the objects in a well-defined order, you have to add an attribute `sortIndex`
to the entity and fetch the objects with a sort descriptor using that key.

When rearranging rows in the table view, you have to update the `sortIndex` attribute
so that it reflects the new order. Unfortunately, there is no built-on or "easy"
method to achieve this goal.

Have a look at [How to implement re-ordering of CoreData records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077568/how-to-implement-re-ordering-of-coredata-records) for more information. In particular the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15625897/1187415 looks promising, but I did not test it
myself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Just one more question, the sortIndex should be an attribute of the Core Data Entity right?

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd: Yes, exactly.