# managedContext.insertObject extra argument in call `atIndex` in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So here is my code: (I want to re-order the table and update Core Data):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entity, inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    let entityObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    entityObject.setValue(content, forKey: key)

    self.managedContext.insertObject(entityObject, atIndex: 0)      //ERROR HERE

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {

    }
}
```

I've seen similar code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15625897/2603230) but why mine isn't working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided is not doing the same thing you did here. What he did there was removing and inserting object in to a array of `Playlist`.

If you really want to re-order the table and update Core Data accordingly, you may want to add a `index` field to your Core Data model, and update it with the index of cell every time the cell is moved.

So you can populate the data to table view in order of the `index` filed, and keep cell order synchronized with data model.

Answer (score 1):

First of all a side note: The objects in `NSManagedObjectContext` are unordered so there is no method to insert an object at an particular index.

Since the object is inserted already two lines above in the method `NSManagedObject(entity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)`, delete the line which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Vadian, you do not need to worry about ordering the Managed Object Context.

To update the UI you should run -

```
"tableView.reloadData"
```

in addition to above code.